# Is there any way to remove the executing code in LaTeX when executing an R command in knitr?

Tags: r, latex

Assuming a simple R script like this:

```
## ---- rcoding
plot(sin)
```

I want to output the above plot inn my LaTeX file, however when I use knitr like this:

```
<<echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
read_chunk("code.R")

<<rcoding>>=

@
```

It outputs the plot, but also the `plot(sin)` code right above it. Is there any way to remove the `plot(sin)` part in my LaTeX output so it only shows the plot and nothing else? I was thinking about some kind of argument to add to the `<<rcoding>>=`.

Comment: What is `<<rcoding>>=` supposed to do in your code?

Comment: @David Klotz: It basically indicates which part in my R script that it should retrieve. So in my R script file (code.R) I have the plot function under the code chunk label `## ---- rcoding` and when I then write `<<rcoding>>=` in my LaTeX, it retrieves the code chunk "rcoding" from the R script which is the plot. This is the guide I'm using under "External R Scripts": https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Knitr

Comment: Following that guide, you would need to add another `@` after your second line of code.  Like you suggested, I would try changing your `rcoding` line to `<<rcoding, echo = FALSE>>='

Comment: @DavidKlotz: That worked, thank you!